# Woocommerce add 15% discount to a product if quantity is greater than or equal to 6

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add a wholesale functionality for every 6th quantity and more for each product, it will automatically be converted to a wholesale price which is 15% less on the original price. How can I do this to my woocommercce?

Answer (score 0):

Woo Discount Rules can does that.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-discount-rules/

Free version works if you doesn't require the rules to be apply to certain customer or roles

Comment: That's a nice plugin, but as much as possible I want to do it in hardcoded.